# GUI update timer non-static variables cannot be accessed from a static context

Tags: java, swing, static, java-2d, repaint

When I run the below code I get two of the same error: non-static method cannot be referenced from static context. The two offending lines are:

```
gladiator[a] = new Gladiator();
graphic.startUpdate();
```

If I change the Gladiator class to static, that error goes away, but won't that make it so individual Gladiators can't have their own independent variables?

The startUpdate() method won't let me change it to static without throwing an error which says "modifier static is only allowed in constant variable declaration". Clearly I am using my update timer in the wrong place. Any ideas?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test extends JPanel{

    abstract class graphic {
        public Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        public int[] location = new int[] {screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2};

        void startUpdate() {
            new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                repaint();

            }
        }).start();


        }


    }

    public class Gladiator extends graphic {

        void draw(final Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillArc(location[0], location[1], 100, 100, 45, 90);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillArc((location[0]+50-10),(location[1]+50-10), 20, 20, 0, 360);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);


    }

    public void setLocation(int x, int y){
        //this.location[0] = x;
        //this.location[1] = y;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gladiator[] gladiator = new Gladiator[2];
        ArrayList<Gladiator> gladiatorList = new ArrayList<Gladiator>();
        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation
        (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        jf.add(new Test());

        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);

        for (int a =0; a < 2; a++) {
        gladiator[a] = new Gladiator();
        gladiatorList.add(gladiator[a]);        
        System.out.println("add "+a);
        }
        graphic.startUpdate();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your mission should be this: *learn the basics of Java*. Once you have that covered you can get back to your game project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of problems, the errors you get are just hiding the rest.

But to get you started:

The abstract class graphic should probably extend [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html). Instead of the draw method you should override [paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29). Both graphic and Gladiator should be in its own file, not inside Test.
Location array could be called int x and int y respectively to make it easier in the future. 
For more info on repaint see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Comment: Definitely gives me something to go on. I appreciate your help - I am learning java on my own.